# Too many entries in the ActiveMQ log

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, activemq-classic

Our ActiveMQ log has too many entries, similar to this (simplified):

```
2017-03-16 09:58:11,721 | INFO  | Adding Connection: ConnectionInfo {...} | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: ...
2017-03-16 09:58:11,724 | INFO  | Removing Session: SessionInfo {...} | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: ...
2017-03-16 09:58:11,724 | INFO  | Removing Connection: ConnectionInfo {...} | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: ...
2017-03-16 09:58:11,725 | INFO  | Adding Connection: ConnectionInfo {...} | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: ...
2017-03-16 09:58:11,725 | INFO  | Removing Session: SessionInfo {...} | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: ...
2017-03-16 09:58:11,725 | INFO  | Removing Connection: ConnectionInfo {...} | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: ...
```

Practically in every millisecond we have these `Adding Connection`, `Removing Session` and `Removing Connection` triples. As result the 10*10 MB log file contains only a few minutes traffic, and it is practically useless.

We connect to ActiveMQ broker with a Java Enterprise application running in JBoss.

1. Does anyone know the reason of these overwhelming messages?
2. Is there a means to log just the traffic, i.e. message has been sent to queue and dispatched from queue, and suppress these useless entries?

Thank you for any help or hint in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you turned the LoggingBrokerPlugin(http://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor.html) on in the activemq.xml.

You can just turn on logConsumerEvents and logProducerEvents logs, instead of using logAll.